# Are electrostatic effects temperature dependent?

Tags: electrochemistry

A charged particle like an ion, does its repulsive or attractive effect on other particles change with temperature? Are electrostatic effects temperature dependent?

Comment: What "electrostatic effects"?

Comment: There is nothing in the Coulomb's law that is temperature dependent.

Comment: Well ...... there is a relativistic effect that means the force between two charged particles does depend upon their velocity (see e.g. https://newt.phys.unsw.edu.au/einsteinlight/jw/module2_FEB.htm), and higher temperature does mean a wider velocity distribution ... But for any chemical system under reasonable conditions this can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The strength of the electric charge does *not* change with temperature (unless approaching that of the Big Bang). However, *effects* of the charges do change with temperature. For example, at low temperatures (near 0 K), [ions can form arrays in space](https://phys.org/news/2020-06-arrays-strontium-rydberg-atoms-quantum.html), though their charges repel. The [history of Bose-Einstein condensates](https://web.mit.edu/physics/news/physicsatmit/physicsatmit_02_bec.pdf) begins with trapped ions, extending to neutral gases.

Comment: What I'm looking at is similar to ions being able to form ordered structures at low temperatures, but, that their charges repel at higher temperatures. Is that supported by theory? If yes, what is the reason for that?

Comment: No. The interaction is temperature independent. But higher temperature means higher thermal energy, which may be able to overcome the electrostatic interactions.

Comment: @Moishe I object. Your first link tells about arrays of _neutral_ atoms (sure, they are in a highly unusual state, but still).

Comment: @IvanNeretin, yes, but a Rydberg atom is *almost* an ion, so please don't get excited ;-)

Comment: An ion _with an electron around it_! Well, you may have the same in any piece of any metal. There is no need to look for exotic states of matter.